# The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

```
ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),  
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [Column(
                  children: [
                    Buttons(),
                        Text("Premium Exclusive"),
                        Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          image: DecorationImage(
                                              image: AssetImage(
                                                  'assets/images/components/shop/shop_giftcard.png')
                                          )
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          image: DecorationImage(
                                              image: AssetImage(
                                                  'assets/images/components/shop/shop_giftcard.png')
                                          )
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ]
                              ),
                              Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      width:  100,
                                      height: 200,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          image: DecorationImage(
                                              image: AssetImage(
                                                  'assets/images/components/shop/shop_giftcard.png')
                                          )
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 200,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          image: DecorationImage(
                                              image: AssetImage(
                                                  'assets/images/components/shop/shop_giftcard.png')
                                          )
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ]
                              ),
                            ]
                        ),
```

Hi, I'm flutter beginner.. When I put the image in container in listview, It doesn't apper and error like a picture below. I don't understand and how to resolve that in the error messages.. please give some advice and aprreciate that,,

---error---
Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/assets/images/components/shop/shop_giftcard.png" (404)

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================

Is it problem related with image file that I put in asset folder in not correctly?

Comment: Could you please include your `pubspec.yaml`'s assets section?

Comment: check your `pubspec.yaml` file, scroll down and check your image assets is alreay input correctly or not

Answer (score 0):

make this change to all AssetImage widget. make sure pubspec.yaml spacing is correct.

First in your pubspec.yaml file

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/components/shop/
```

then in you code

```
AssetImage(                                                
  'assets/images/components/shop/shop_giftcard.png' 
)
```